# centos 6.2 remote kickstart installation

Tags: linux, centos, installation, kickstart

Using centos 6.2 I would like to kickoff installation via a kickstart file on a remote machine.  In centos 5 I noticed that there is an initial prompt where the kickstart location can be set, but I haven't seen anything similar in the centos6 boot process.

At the moment I've attempted to use the netinstall ISO, but it seems to only give the option to select an "installation image".

Is there a way to point to a remote kickstart file (using minimal or netinstall ISOs) without the need to create a custom ISO?

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not do a PXE install?

Comment: Just starting with what I know.  PXE would be nice since I wouldn't even need to burn a disc to get started.  I've briefly looked over PXE install, but haven't found a good guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the netinstall or regular DVD, Press `TAB` to edit your kernel boot options.

[image]

After doing so, you will receive a prompt where you can add kernel options or change the boot lines.

In the example below, I've added a basic command to fetch the kickstart from a remote server.

*Note - the format is no longer `linux ks=http://blahblah.com/ks.cfg`. You just need to append your settings to the existing line.*

[image]

Comment: Yeah, nobody really announced the change.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good link for [PXE](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/PXE). Follow the "rescue mode" link for a quick working example.

The decribed example is from CentOS 4.4 but it should work with newer versions as well.
I took the **pxelinux.0** file from Ubuntu 10.4 LTS - that was newer than the CentOS 5.3 or SLES10 SP2 version for the PXE-Bootstrap-loader.